# Why the binary.Size() return (-1)?

Tags: go

The code snippet likes this:

```
package main
import (
    "fmt"
    "encoding/binary"
    "reflect"
)

const (
    commandLen = 1
    bufLen int = 4
)

func main(){
    fmt.Printf("%v %v\n", reflect.TypeOf(commandLen), reflect.TypeOf(bufLen))
    fmt.Printf("%d %d", binary.Size(commandLen), binary.Size(bufLen))
}
```

And the output is:

```
int int
-1 -1
```

I think since the types of commandLen and bufLen are int, and from "Programming in golang", 
the int should be int32 or int64 which depending on the implementation, so I think the binary.Size() should return a value, not (-1).

Why the binary.Size() return (-1)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### tl;dr

`int` is not a fixed-length type, so it won't work. Use something that has a fixed length, for example `int32`.

#### Explanation

This might look like a bug but it is actually not a bug. The [documentation of `Size()`](http://golang.org/pkg/encoding/binary/#Size) says:

> Size returns how many bytes Write would generate to encode the value v, which must be a
>   fixed-size value or a slice of **fixed-size values**, or a pointer to such data.

A fixed-size value is a value that is not dependent on the architecture and the size is known
beforehand. This is the case for `int32` or `int64` but not for `int` as it depends on the 
environment's architecture. See the [documentation of `int`](http://golang.org/pkg/builtin/#int).

If you're asking yourself why `Size()` enforces this, consider encoding an `int` on your
64 bit machine and decoding the data on a remote 32 bit machine. This is only possible if you have length encoded types, which `int` is not. So you either have to store the size along with the type or enforce fixed-length types which the developers did.

This is reflected in the [`sizeof()`](http://code.google.com/p/go/source/browse/src/pkg/encoding/binary/binary.go?name=go1.1.2#306) function of `encoding/binary` that computes the size:

```
case reflect.Uint8, reflect.Uint16, reflect.Uint32, reflect.Uint64,
       reflect.Int8, reflect.Int16, reflect.Int32, reflect.Int64,
       reflect.Float32, reflect.Float64, reflect.Complex64, reflect.Complex128:
       return int(t.Size()), nil
```

As you can see, there are all number types listed but `reflect.Int`.